# D Latch as Transparent latch

Tags: latch, sequential-logic

I was reading an article over latches and suddenly a line struck me which says "D latches are also known as Transparent latches.". Anyone who can explain me why D latches are known as transparent latches. Thanks in advance.

Comment: how does the output relate to the input when clock is low? and when clock is high?

Comment: Latches are described as being "transparent" because they are not edge-triggered. As long as the enable input is asserted, the output will follow the input. Compare this to a D flip-flop, whose output can only change on a clock edge.

Comment: so we are talking about latches  versus FlipFlops, right?

Comment: @CalebReister Can you please explain me the term you have written "Clock edge". thanks in advance.

Comment: @problematicDude A clock edge occurs when the clock signal transitions from 0 to 1 (rising edge) or 1 to 0 (falling edge).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the input latch control is in the "capture" state the Q output will follow the state of the D input. When the input control changed to the "latch" state the most recent level on the D input which has propagated to the Q output will be held (latched) at the output.

The term transparent comes from the capture mode is active and the input can be seen at the output.

Comment: maybe you should add a truth table and diagram as well for clarity

Answer (score 0):

A D latch is described as being "transparent" because the input "flows through" to the output as long as the enable bit is asserted. Compare this to a D flip-flop, whose output can only update on a clock edge. In order to illustrate this, take a look at the waveforms below:

[image: D latch vs. D flip-flop waveforms (created using WaveDrom)]

Comment: You timing diagram is a bit misleading. A D latch does not have a clock input and the D input does not have to be clock synchronous. This would be clearer if your D input was **not** aligned to clock leading edges.

Comment: @BruceAbbott I see what you mean. However, note that there are division lines on each rising edge, and that the transitions occur distinctly *after* the divisions.

Comment: _"the transitions occur distinctly after the divisions"_ Yes, as if they were caused by them. If I was confused then others could be too.